# PNG cruncher error ? Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. on android studio window 7 environment?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Exception in thread "png-cruncher_20" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\IMP_soft\SDK\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds

**Its only occurs when i am trying to integrate google analytics, otherwise my project works successfully**